# How to make a UDP call in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, udp, fsockopen

In PHP you can make a UDP call like this (from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)):

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 13, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "\n");
    echo fread($fp, 26);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Is it possible to make a UDP call in Classic ASP?  If so, what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: As far as I know you need a special component to do this in ASP, but I haven't been able to locate this component, which is likely no longer active/maintained.

Comment: Possible answer: http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/howto/udp/vbscript/

Answer (score 0):

You should use activex component to do this in classic asp.
There are at least 3 products, you can choose one of them.

- [Udp ActiveX Control](http://www.powertcp.com/winsock-activex-udp-control.aspx) by Dart Communications
- [ActiveXperts Network Component](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/) by ActiveXperts Software
- [Socket / SSL Component](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/socket-features.asp) by Chilkat Software